# How to terminate a neo4j connection using py2neo?

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, py2neo, flask-restful

I am creating a flask restful api to import data in to neo4j using Py2neo. As authentication is to be done in every request, I want my neo4j connection to be terminated at the end of each request such that subsequent requests with different auth info wouldn't use the previous credentials.

Is there any way to do this in Py2neo?

Comment: You could initialize a new Graph instance every request.

Comment: Would love to get a little more info on this. I have a Jupyter notebook running and the connection dies sometimes -- would be great to purposefully close the connection and reopen it so that it doesn't just hang and die over the course of time.